# Having trouble mapping solaris drive paths to physical disks

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, solaris, zfs, solaris-10

I have a supermicro box with 24 drives in front and 12 drives in back. It's running x86 solaris 10 with zfs. Here is the output of zpool status:

```
NAME                         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        pool0                        DEGRADED     0     0     0
          raidz1-0                   DEGRADED     0     0     0
            c0t50014EE0AD5A2780d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE6ABA1D6FBd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE6ABA5D381d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE6ABB878DAd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE6ABBA2AE8d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            spare-5                  DEGRADED     0     0 3.57K
              c0t50014EE6ABBA6C1Dd0  DEGRADED     0     0    58  too many errors
              c0t50014EE656653771d0  ONLINE       0     0    36
            c0t50014EE6ABBA7F2Cd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-1                   ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE6ABBA8B90d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE6ABBA14DDd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE6ABBA51F6d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE6ABBA96A7d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE6ABBA781Fd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE6ABBA9520d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE6ABBAA6DBd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-2                   ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE057F97C17d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE05803A730d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE6010E0D7Fd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE6010FC38Fd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE6010FEAB4d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE6010FFFA7d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE6564E9983d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-3                   ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE058044DA5d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE65664DB43d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE65664F040d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE0580386EAd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE0580442C9d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE656568B2Bd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE656651CE1d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-4                   ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE656654D76d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE6011033C6d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE6566549B7d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE6566561C4d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE6566578CCd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE60110246Bd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c0t50014EE65665731Cd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
        spares
          c0t50014EE656653771d0      INUSE     currently in use
```

My problem is that I can't seem to find a way of mapping these drive id's to the physical drives so I can replace them.
Here is the output from another cmdline tool that I forget the name of:

```
Ap_Id                          Receptacle   Occupant     Condition  Information
When         Type         Busy     Phys_Id
c9                             connected    configured   unknown
unavailable  scsi-sas     n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi
c9::es/ses0                    connected    configured   unknown    LSI CORP SAS2X36
unavailable  ESI          n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::es/ses0
c9::smp/expd0                  connected    configured   unknown    LSI CORP SAS2X36
unavailable  smp          n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::smp/expd0
c9::w50014ee6aba1d6fb,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6ABA1D6FBd0s0(sd21)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee6aba1d6fb,0
c9::w50014ee6aba5d381,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6ABA5D381d0s0(sd7)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee6aba5d381,0
c9::w50014ee6abb878da,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6ABB878DAd0s0(sd17)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee6abb878da,0
c9::w50014ee6abba51f6,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6ABBA51F6d0s0(sd13)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee6abba51f6,0
c9::w50014ee6abba96a7,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6ABBA96A7d0s0(sd16)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee6abba96a7,0
c9::w50014ee6abba781f,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6ABBA781Fd0s0(sd25)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee6abba781f,0
c9::w50014ee6abba9520,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6ABBA9520d0s0(sd4)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee6abba9520,0
c9::w50014ee6abbaa6db,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6ABBAA6DBd0s0(sd18)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee6abbaa6db,0
c9::w50014ee05803a730,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE05803A730d0s0(sd5)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee05803a730,0
c9::w50014ee6010e0d7f,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6010E0D7Fd0s0(sd26)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee6010e0d7f,0
c9::w50014ee6010fc38f,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6010FC38Fd0s0(sd24)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee6010fc38f,0
c9::w50014ee6010fffa7,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6010FFFA7d0s0(sd15)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee6010fffa7,0
c9::w50014ee6564e9983,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6564E9983d0s0(sd10)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee6564e9983,0
c9::w50014ee058044da5,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE058044DA5d0s0(sd12)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee058044da5,0
c9::w50014ee65664db43,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE65664DB43d0s0(sd9)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee65664db43,0
c9::w50014ee65664f040,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE65664F040d0s0(sd3)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee65664f040,0
c9::w50014ee656568b2b,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE656568B2Bd0s0(sd19)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee656568b2b,0
c9::w50014ee656651ce1,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE656651CE1d0s0(sd6)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee656651ce1,0
c9::w50014ee6011033c6,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6011033C6d0s0(sd14)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee6011033c6,0
c9::w50014ee6566561c4,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6566561C4d0s0(sd11)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee6566561c4,0
c9::w50014ee6566578cc,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6566578CCd0s0(sd22)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee6566578cc,0
c9::w50014ee60110246b,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE60110246Bd0s0(sd20)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee60110246b,0
c9::w50014ee65665731c,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE65665731Cd0s0(sd23)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee65665731c,0
c9::w50014ee656653771,0        connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE656653771d0s0(sd8)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f:scsi::w50014ee656653771,0
c10                            connected    configured   unknown
unavailable  scsi-sas     n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f0:scsi
c10::es/ses1                   connected    configured   unknown    LSI CORP SAS2X28
unavailable  ESI          n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f0:scsi::es/ses1
c10::smp/expd1                 connected    configured   unknown    LSI CORP SAS2X28
unavailable  smp          n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f0:scsi::smp/expd1
c10::w50014ee0ad5a2780,0       connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE0AD5A2780d0s0(sd27)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f0:scsi::w50014ee0ad5a2780,0
c10::w50014ee6abba2ae8,0       connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6ABBA2AE8d0s0(sd33)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f0:scsi::w50014ee6abba2ae8,0
c10::w50014ee6abba6c1d,0       connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6ABBA6C1Dd0s0(sd37)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f0:scsi::w50014ee6abba6c1d,0
c10::w50014ee6abba7f2c,0       connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6ABBA7F2Cd0s0(sd36)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f0:scsi::w50014ee6abba7f2c,0
c10::w50014ee6abba8b90,0       connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6ABBA8B90d0s0(sd28)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f0:scsi::w50014ee6abba8b90,0
c10::w50014ee6abba14dd,0       connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6ABBA14DDd0s0(sd38)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f0:scsi::w50014ee6abba14dd,0
c10::w50014ee057f97c17,0       connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE057F97C17d0s0(sd32)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f0:scsi::w50014ee057f97c17,0
c10::w50014ee6010feab4,0       connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6010FEAB4d0s0(sd29)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f0:scsi::w50014ee6010feab4,0
c10::w50014ee0580386ea,0       connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE0580386EAd0s0(sd35)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f0:scsi::w50014ee0580386ea,0
c10::w50014ee0580442c9,0       connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE0580442C9d0s0(sd34)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f0:scsi::w50014ee0580442c9,0
c10::w50014ee656654d76,0       connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE656654D76d0s0(sd30)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f0:scsi::w50014ee656654d76,0
c10::w50014ee6566549b7,0       connected    configured   unknown    Client Device: /dev/dsk/c0t50014EE6566549B7d0s0(sd31)
unavailable  disk-path    n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,3410@9/pci15d9,400@0/iport@f0:scsi::w50014ee6566549b7,0
c11                            connected    unconfigured unknown
```

Here is the output from iostat -En :

```
c8t0d0           Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2503ABYX-0 Revision: 1S01 Serial No:
Size: 251.06GB <251059544064 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 56 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c8t1d0           Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2503ABYX-0 Revision: 1S01 Serial No:
Size: 251.06GB <251059544064 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 55 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE65664F040d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6ABBA9520d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE05803A730d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE656651CE1d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6ABA5D381d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE656653771d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE65664DB43d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6564E9983d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6566561C4d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE058044DA5d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6ABBA51F6d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6011033C6d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6010FFFA7d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6ABBA96A7d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6ABB878DAd0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6ABBAA6DBd0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE656568B2Bd0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE60110246Bd0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6ABA1D6FBd0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6566578CCd0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE65665731Cd0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6010FC38Fd0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6ABBA781Fd0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6010E0D7Fd0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE0AD5A2780d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6ABBA8B90d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6010FEAB4d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE656654D76d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6566549B7d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE057F97C17d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6ABBA2AE8d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE0580442C9d0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE0580386EAd0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6ABBA7F2Cd0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6ABBA6C1Dd0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 11187 Transport Errors: 26776
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 8882 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 2305 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
c0t50014EE6ABBA14DDd0 Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: ATA      Product: WDC WD2003FYYS-0 Revision: 1D01 Serial No:
Size: 2000.40GB <2000398934016 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
```

As you can see they are all 2TB drives except the 2 small OS drives. I'm hoping that the drive id (c0t5......) is partially derived from the serial # on the drive. The machine has two sas/sata multiport cards with 2 expanders which don't communicate with solaris so I can see things like the serial numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the complete or partial [WWID or WWN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Name) of the disk on its label or record it somewhere in a slot map.

[image]

Also see: [Identify Disks on SuperMicro server running FreeBSD](https://serverfault.com/questions/480524/identify-disks-on-supermicro-server-running-freebsd)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Sas2ircu can see all the drives. I'm running it remotely right now, so I don't know if it will blink the lights, but it gives me a fighting chance now to get the correct drives replaced.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the diskinfo command?

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5166/diskinfo-1m.html